# Regex to extract data in cell and pass to subsequent request where it is needed in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, jmeter, extract, beanshell

I am using this `regex` to extract data in cell and pass to subsequent request where it is needed in `JMeter`.
Using Reg-ex to extract the data in cell:

```
"cell":\["","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)"]}]}
```

Can someone help to enhance it using `beanshell` or store it in array and then pass it to subsequent request?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to extract something from [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) response. Using regular expressions for this is not very recommended.

Be aware that starting from [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) there is a [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which can be used for fetching data from JSON responses using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) language.

The relevant JsonPath expression to get the content of `cell` element will be as simple as:

```
$..cell
```

Going forward please try to include at least essential parts of the response into your question.

Comment: Thanks for response Dmitri T ! We surely try it out. Will update the question in detail.